# How do I (include) a Php page by calling a div id?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I already looked and couldn't find what I was looking for... So if this is already out there somewhere sorry..

What I am trying to do is `<?php include('style/header.php') ?>` but instead of having to include it like that, I would like to call it with `<div class="header"></div>`So when that div is used it gets replaced by whatever is in the php file.

I am doing this because I am working with a CMS editor that does not allow anything but div tags and basic html. However I can still add scripts and php to the page itself, (just not in the content area.) But I can get around this if I can include the php as a div...

If there is anyway I can do this with php, Jquery, or javascript that would be great!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This isn't really that easy to do... you will have to set up urls that return the contents of the a specific php header.  Then when you load the page, you could check the value of the class and then with ajax call the specific page that has the header contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't include a PHP page by calling a div. But you may actually call that php page using JavaScript (ajax), get the data and finally set the data to your div. The solution below uses jQuery so be sure you have loaded jQuery in your page for it to work.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "yourPage.php",
   success: function(data){
     $(".header").html(data);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Well, or you can do an ajax request to an PHP file an obtain the data and fill the div with the received data.

Comment: So there is no way to include it using a div? at all even with something like Ajax? Sorry if this sounds silly web design is not my specialty.

Comment: @redigaffi  How do you do that?

Comment: Check my answer now.

Comment: I couldent get it to work Im probibly messing somthing up.. I tried to make a test document and try it: [here is a screenshot of my code.](https://i.imgur.com/v11yjFK.png)

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery in the page? Be sure to load jQuery for it to work.

Comment: I added Jquery to my test page.... and... IT WORKS!!! The only thing I had to do was change `.text(data);` to `.html(data);` to get it to display properly. THANKS SO MUCH :)